# GDB breakpoint just exits the program and quits GDB

Tags: c, assembly, gdb, breakpoints

I wrote a simple C program and wanted to examine how it works on a lower level in GDB.
I opened and disassembled it and it all works fine.

```
(gdb) disassemble main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0000124d <+0>: endbr32 
   0x00001251 <+4>: lea    ecx,[esp+0x4]
   0x00001255 <+8>: and    esp,0xfffffff0
   0x00001258 <+11>:    push   DWORD PTR [ecx-0x4]
   0x0000125b <+14>:    push   ebp
   0x0000125c <+15>:    mov    ebp,esp
   0x0000125e <+17>:    push   ebx
   0x0000125f <+18>:    push   ecx
   0x00001260 <+19>:    sub    esp,0x10
   0x00001263 <+22>:    call   0x1150 <__x86.get_pc_thunk.bx>
   0x00001268 <+27>:    add    ebx,0x2d60
   0x0000126e <+33>:    mov    eax,gs:0x14
   0x00001274 <+39>:    mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0xc],eax
   0x00001277 <+42>:    xor    eax,eax
   0x00001279 <+44>:    mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x14],0x0
   0x00001280 <+51>:    sub    esp,0xc
   0x00001283 <+54>:    lea    eax,[ebx-0x1fc0]
   and so on...
```

When I try to set a breakpoint it seems to work:

```
(gdb) break *0x00001255
Breakpoint 1 at 0x1255
```

However when I run, this happens:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/tim/Desktop/simple32 

[9]+  Stopped                 gdb simple32
```

Instead of hitting the breakpoint, it just stops the program and exits GDB. I tried this with a 64-bit and 32-bit binary and it always does this no matter what.

Not only that but it worked perfectly fine before, and today it just stopped working...

Please help.

BTW when I just run the program normally in gdb with no breakpoints, it works perfectly fine:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/tim/Desktop/simple32 
Please enter a value from 1 - 9
3
Your value is 3
[Inferior 1 (process 24925) exited normally]
(gdb)
```

Comment: `Stopped` is not the same as `exited`.  A stopped process is suspended in the background.   It can be seen with `ps` and retrieved with the `fg` command.

Comment: I know that, but why does it exit gdb? It is not meant to do that.

Comment: Since gdb has stopped, not exited (as shown by the message) what happens when you type fg?

Comment: I have solved this issue myself. Instead of compiling like this: gcc prog.c -o prog, I compiled like this: gcc -no-pie prog.c -o prog. This turned it from ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable to ELF 64-bit LSB executable. The pie executable just doesn't work with gdb since the pie executable has smaller addresses.